# Which is the best service to run scheduled docker container which take several days?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, serverless

I have checked most of the GCP services and Cloud Functions & Run are awesome, but they have limited runtime, also the App engine is designed for website hosting, not for temporary backend tasks.

so is there any service that supports my case, with serverless behavior where just pay for usage?

Comment: You have not specified what your container does. Typically for your use case, I use Compute Engine Container Optimized OS, where a container needs to run for long periods of time (anything longer than one hour) or needs more computer services than serverless offers. When the container finishes its task, it deletes itself via an API call.

Comment: IMO GKE autopilot is the best, if your container comply with the security restrictions. Else, Compute Engine is always the solution.

Comment: @JohnHanley, actually, it's updating the database by collecting the data from different resources, but for some restrictions, I collect this data via calling some APIs, with a specific number of requests per second, so it takes hours and some times days, and it should execute once a month.

Answer (score 0):

Autopilot  GKE is designed to reduce the operational cost of managing clusters, optimize your clusters for production, and yield higher workload availability.

[Autopilot overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview)

I hope this might help you